# How can I get rid of this unwanted rerendering loop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This a my code as of now (in App.tsx):

```
const [taskState, setTaskState] = useState([] as TaskModel[])

useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/task")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(responseParamerter => {
                var a = responseParamerter
                a.map((task: TaskModel) => {
                    const newTask = {
                        TaskID: task.TaskID,
                        Status: task.Status,
                        TaskName: task.TaskName,
                        TaskText: task.TaskText
                    } as TaskModel
                    setTaskState([...taskState, newTask])
                })
            })
    }, [taskState])
```

But now comes my problem, setTaskState triggers a rerender for some reason (or it triggers the useEffect at least) but the useEffect uses the setTaskState which triggers the useEffect. The number of fetch requests are quickly in the hundreds but I don't know what I can do about it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the `taskState` from the dependencies list. what your code saying is fetch me the new data every time `taskState` is changed.

Comment: @Naresh Do you mean the [taskState] at the end? I tried but everytime I save it puts it back in. I even deactivated eslint but it still does it on it's own. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Use `setTaskState(tasks => [...tasks, newTask])` instead of `setTaskState([...taskState, newTask])`

Comment: @reichenwald can you try disabling eslint for that particular line only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to set tasks one by one when you can just set them all at once:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/task")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(responseParamerter => {
                setTaskState(responseParamerter
                    .map((task: TaskModel) => {
                        return {
                            TaskID: task.TaskID,
                            Status: task.Status,
                            TaskName: task.TaskName,
                            TaskText: task.TaskText
                        } as TaskModel

                    }))
            })
    }, [])
```

You are using Array.prototype.map wrong, you are [ignoring the return value of the callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map)

Answer (score 0):

Here the `useEffect` hook will be called every time you update the `taskState` and you are updating the `taskState` everytime you get a response from api.

```
const [taskState, setTaskState] = useState([] as TaskModel[])

useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/task")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(responseParamerter => {
                var a = responseParamerter
                const newTasks = a.map((task: TaskModel) => {
                    const newTask = {
                        TaskID: task.TaskID,
                        Status: task.Status,
                        TaskName: task.TaskName,
                        TaskText: task.TaskText
                    } as TaskModel
                    return newTask;
                });
                // this wil append prev tasks and new tasks
                setTaskState(tasks => [...tasks, ...newTasks]);
                // if you only want new tasks, then you should do
                // setTaskState(newTasks)
            })
    }, [])
```

removing the `taskState` from the dependencies list will call your `useEffect` hook only when your component is mounted.

Comment: You shouldn't be referencing `taskState` when setting it. Use a callback instead, otherwise you'll be closing around a stale value.

Comment: OP is using map wrong, it is [ignoring the return value of the callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map)